# old PHP Project that needs organizing

Tags: php, mysql, oop, project-management

I am working in a company that owns a website which I find very difficult to coop with, not because of my lack of experience in PHP but due to the fact the code is written in a very old and low quality, written with no OOP.

What I can see in the APP:

- html page ,
- Php Page
- Template
- mysql structured like the Pablo Picasso paintings, no foreign keys, no constraints nothing

I only see code written and rewritten over and over I just myself can't understand how do people mingle in this ocean of codes vomit ? When I tried to contact one of my colleagues to understand more about it, he told me that its taking them more and more time to achieve tasks already emphasizing on the fact that complexity is gradually increasing and they  can't do anything anymore because a massive amount of data has been initiated.

has anyone had any similar situation? any advice ? maybe there is a way to fix this chaos ?

Any post would be appreciated !

Comment: Not really on-topic for Stack Overflow. We can't offer anything resembling useful *objective* advice based on what you've posted.

Comment: _mysql structured like the Pablo Picasso paintings_. Nice...

Comment: Welcome to the [big ball of mud](http://laputan.org/mud)! We all have to make that experience at least once.

Comment: I suppose I'd aim for Piet Mondrian or maybe Donald Judd instead.

Comment: "has anyone had any similar situation?" Unfortunately pretty much every PHP project I've ever worked on. This question would be better suited to programmers.se I think

Comment: I'm sure your assessment is 100% correct, but a separate point for anyone else reading - just because it doesn't have OOP doesn't mean it's an outdated project/software. People forget that OOP in PHP was written in as an _after-thought_. PHP was never intended to be OOP, but felt that it needed to jump on the bandwagon so it wasn't left in the dust of the OOP craze.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Picking a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) and re-implementing the application using that will significantly improve the maintainability of an application.

If you want a way of justifying this from a cost perspective, do an audit with a [SQL injection testing tool](http://sqlmap.org/) and you'll probably find a million things wrong. Some of these things will be so terrifying you'll be tempted to just burn the codebase to the ground and start over.

The best approach is to migrate, feature by feature, page by page, from the old application to the new one. Often you can do this by creating a content map, adding rewrite rules to map particular URLs to the legacy code, then start deleting these rules one by one as they're no longer required.

Remember to have a robust mapping table if you ever change URLs. Returning a [301 Permanent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) redirect is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I take these projects a lot. Breathe. It's part of the industry.

Simply break the project up in to functions. Design a flow diagram. Program the flow diagram.

Software rebuilt.

Comment: This is good advice. I also find that utilizing an established framework/platform with this approach is useful.